# Poor performance with Rack::Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rack-cache

I have Rack::Cache set up as the very top (last) middleware in my stack. My app is hosted on heroku cedar, so Rack::Cache is responsible for static assets as well.

It's backed by the heroku memcached product, and configured like this:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
  :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
  :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
  :allow_reload => false
}
config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=2592000"
```

It's running on thin.

I'm testing performance on an image file, using ab.

`ab -n100 -c10 https://example.com/foo.jpg`

Looking in my logs, all the requests are a cache hit ("fresh"). But the performance is poor, only around 6 requests/sec. I know that Rack::Cache isn't going to perform as well as a dedicated http proxy, but I certainly expected higher throughput than this.

**update**
I don't how the heck I didn't think of this before, but my benchmark is indeed maxing out my internet connection. If I do the same test with robots.txt instead of a jpg, I get 20 requests/sec (and still max out the downstream).

Comment: Can you test it with Rack::Cache and without and give us results?

Comment: great question. without Rack::Cache it is 3 requests/sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed the URL in your post is HTTPS.  I had an issue on the cedar stack with hostname-based SSL where certain requests (for both static assets and otherwise) would experience high latency even though the logs said the queue time was 0ms and the service time was 5-10ms. Here's Heroku's support response (what he doesn't mention is that varnish doesn't cache resources coming from cedar apps, regardless, despite it being present in the stack when running hostname based SSL):

> We're not entirely sure what is causing this, but we suspect Varnish
>   is to blame. Normally, with the Cedar stack, Varnish is not present.
>   But when the SSL Hostname add-on is used, Varnish is added back into
>   the response process. There's no need to use both Rack::Cache and
>   Varnish.
>
> I'd like to suggest removing Varnish from the picture to see if it
>   helps. The way to do this is to move SSL to our new SSL add-on, SSL
>   Endpoint. SSL Endpoint is technically still in beta, but it will be
>   generally available soon and it will cost the same as SSL Hostname.
>   It's the future of SSL on Heroku and it's better in every way.
>
> http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint-beta2
>   user: beta 
>   pass: **********
>
> The downside to moving is you have to update DNS, but once this is
>   done, Varnish will be out of the picture and we'll be able to get a
>   better idea of whether or not it's the problem.
>
> We also considered the possibility that your current SSL endpoint, an
>   Amazon ELB, is bad and needs to be replaced. But if that were the
>   case, many of the requests would be slow or failing, not just a random
>   single slow request. Swapping out the current ELB would also involve a
>   DNS change. Moving to the new SSL Endpoint add-on will make a
>   situation like this easier in the future - if swapping out the ELB is
>   necessary a DNS change would not be needed.
>
> For now, I think moving to SSL Endpoint will be best.

Granted, the latencies I were seeing sometimes got up into the 30-60 SECOND range, which is obviously quite a bit worse than you're seeing. When I run the same apache bench commands against static assets on some of my (HTTPS) cedar apps, I don't do much better (10-15 req/s).  When I increase concurrency to 50 or 100, RPS goes up to as much as 30.  On Varnish fronted bamboo HTTPS apps, however, I can get it up over 50 req/s for a static asset. If my computer could handle higher concurrency, I suspect it would go even higher. And my internet connection is high latency since it's on a cellular network.

Comment: epic answer! im using endpoint SSL, so the weird varnish layer is not an issue. your comparison benchmarks are somewhat reassuring, maybe there is higher concurrency available then i can observe locally. luckily the vast majority of my assets are on a cdn.